# A counterexample to a statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, gaussian-integers

**Question** Give an example that $z\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$, $d\geq1$, $|z|^2$ is a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$ but $z$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$.

**Problem** I understand that if $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ is a UFD then the above is NOT true since $z=xy\implies|z|^2=|x|^2|y|^2$ so $|x|=1$ or $|y|=1$ therefore $x$ or $y$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ hence $z$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ then prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$. So $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ cannot be a UFD, for example, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ can be $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ or $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. But what about a specific example?

Comment: I don't understand. $z$ is non-prime : $z = (a + b \sqrt{-d})(c + e \sqrt{-d})$ hence $|z|^2 = (a^2+b^2 d)(c^2+e^2 d)$, which is non-prime..?

Comment: @user1952009 that shows that $z$ cannot be *irreducible*. In a non-UFD, that is not the same as $z$ not being *prime*.

Comment: @user1952009 Not if the ring is not a UFD. For example, $(2)$ is not a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, even though $2$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such example. In particular, if $|\alpha|^2$ is a prime number, then $\alpha\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]$ is a prime ideal, and hence $\alpha$ is prime.

If you've seen any algebraic number theory, this follows from the fact that the ideal norm $N(\alpha\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}])$ is equal to $|\alpha|^2$.

Otherwise, let $\alpha = x+y\sqrt{-d}$ where $x^2+dy^2=p$ for some prime $p$. First observe that as a group under addition, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]\cong\mathbb Z^2$ via the isomorphism $a+b\sqrt{-d}\mapsto (a,b)$.

Under this isomorphism, the map
$$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]\to \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]\\a+b\sqrt{-d}\mapsto \alpha(a+b\sqrt{-d})$$
corresponds to 
$$\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb Z^2\\\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} x&-dy\\y &x\end{pmatrix}}_{\Gamma}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$$
from which it follows that 
$$[\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]:\alpha\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]] = [\mathbb Z^2:\Gamma\mathbb Z^2] =\det\Gamma = p$$

so that $$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]/\alpha\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]\cong \mathbb F_p.$$

Since the quotient is a field, $\alpha$ must be prime.

Comment: I'm missing some concepts. if $\alpha$ wasn't prime, we would have $xy =   \alpha w$ with $x,y$ non-divisible by $\alpha$. how $N(\alpha \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]) = p$ or $\det \Gamma = p$ does imply that there is no such $x,y$  ? for the second we would have $xy \equiv 0$ with $x,y$ non-zero in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}] / \alpha \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$, which wouldn't be a field ? and the first  ?

Comment: An element is prime if and only if the principal ideal it generates is prime (this follows from the definition). And an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ is prime if and only if $ R/I$ is an integral domain. The norm condition shows that  $\langle\alpha\rangle$ has index $p$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]$. The fact that $\langle\alpha\rangle$ has index $p$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]$ shows that the quotient must be $\mathbb F_p$.